# Datos especificos de una consulta Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una tabla donde estoy guardando todos datos comunes a varias tablas,

Tabla DatosBasico(id, grupo, nombre).

En un formulario tengo varios grupos de datos, genero, categoria, edades, etc. así que hago la consulta

```
$datosBase = DatosBasicos::where('grupo', 'genero')
->orwhere('grupo','edades')
->pluck('id', 'grupo', 'nombre');
```

La pregunta es, una vez enviados los datos a la vista, cómo hago que en el campo select que corresponda solo aparezcan las edades o genero según el caso?

o es mejor separar la consulta quedando:

```
$genero = DatosBasicos::where('grupo', 'genero')->pluck('id', 'nombre');
$edades = DatosBasicos::where('grupo', 'edades')->pluck('id', 'nombre');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes pasar a la vista la variable $datosBase haciendo una consulta como esta:

```
$datosBase = DatosBasicos::where('grupo', 'genero')->orwhere('grupo','edades')
->get();
```

Luego en la vista filtras la colección según lo que necesites para cada uno de los selects:

```
$generos = $datosBase->where('grupo', 'genero');

$edades = $datosBase->where('grupo', 'edades');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, considero que esta soluciona la duda

Comment: @JuanFelipeGonzalezSanchez probaste el código? Porque los segundos `where` están mal, no son métodos estáticos, hay que usar `$datosBase->where()`. Y por otro lado te convendría hacer el `pluck()` al final para tener solo el nombre y el ID.

Comment: @azeos tienes razón, ya modifique la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero traería todo y después filtraría para pasarle a la vista lo que haga falta, similar a lo que dice ManuelV.

```
$datosBase = DatosBasicos::where('grupo', 'genero')->orWhere('grupo','edades')->get();

$generos = $datosBase->where('grupo', 'genero')->pluck('nombre', 'id');
$edades = $datosBase->where('grupo', 'edades')->pluck('nombre', 'id');
```

Un par de cosas:

- El [`orWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) va con  `W` mayúscula, lo tenés escrito con minúscula.
- [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) lleva máximo 2 parámetros, no 3. El 2do es la key, no el primero.
- Tené en cuenta que en `$datosBase` estás trabajando con [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) y en `$generos` y `$edades` ya estás trabajando con una [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections).

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a revisar los conceptos y diferencias entre Eloquent y Collection